# What is the proper way to initiate network communication based on receiving a Broadcast Intent?

Tags: android, multithreading, broadcastreceiver, android-c2dm, android-networking

I'm getting started with Google's C2DM.  Part of this process involves receiving a Broadcast Intent when registration has occurred.  In [Google's official C2DM documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/), the example code shows the following comment in the BrodcastReceiver's onReceive() method:

```
// Send the registration ID to the 3rd party site that is sending the messages.
// This should be done in a separate thread.
```

However, everything I've read, including [the documentation for BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), suggests that starting a thread from onReceive() will almost certainly cause problems, because as soon as onReceive() has returned, the process will likely soon be killed.

It's possible that someone just made a mistake, and that I should just disregard the comment about using a separate thread, but I'm guessing there's a reason they said it, even if it's misleading.

Is there a reason one can't or shouldn't use the network from the same thread as onReceive() before returning?  If doing so is problematic, what's the proper way to handle what must be a common situation, even outside of C2DM?  Starting a Service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, after doing some more research, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5674518/1427098), and [the selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5676888/1427098) states that `onReceive()` runs on the UI thread.  This hadn't occurred to me -- since this is a Manifest-declared receiver, as far as I knew, there *was* no UI thread.

Since you can't do networking on the UI thread on Android, that answers the first part of my question:

- You both shouldn't and *can't* initiate network communication from `onReceive()`.

The fact that we're on the UI thread makes it almost look like an [ASyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is appropriate, but that has the same issues as manually starting another thread.  So it appears that a `Service` is the only option.

Comment: `AsyncTask` is not appropriate here. Basically _any_ asynchronous operation is inappropriate for `onReceive()`. Take a look at `onReceive()` documentation for details. Your best bet is to start a `Service` which initiates the network communication.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'd thought of that before, but I was excited to find out we were on the UI thread, and forgot about that.  Thanks.