# Write data from multiple broadcast receivers into a single file

Tags: android, file-io, broadcastreceiver

In my app I am receiving data at `onReceive()` of various Broadcast receivers. I need to write the intent data I receive into a single file. Every time I receive an intent at any of 4 broadcast receivers I open the same file to write and close it. Sometime many `onReceive()` are invoked and I need to.

I want to know what is the best mechanism for writing to file. I explored on synchronization, use of `Queue` etc. But these were good mechanism for writing from multiple threads.

So my Question is each `onReceive()` equivalent to a thread here?

If yes which mechanism is best to write to a single file on SD card.

If no, Just a regular write is fine(without any locking/synchronization etc)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674518/does-broadcastreceiver-onreceive-always-run-in-the-ui-thread

So, unless you use a handler, it should be fine.

Comment: So,You mean since onReceive() runs on UI thread, there is no chance of different onRecieve() method open the file simultaneously for write? Thanks.

Comment: Correct, onReceive() runs on the UI thread. So you do not need to worry about something else trying to access the same file concurrently, as long as you don't have code elsewhere that would cause such a conflict.