# update UI from BroadCastReceiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

How can I update the main thread from a BroadCastReceiver. I have a BroadCastReceiver which receives a string and I need to set the text for a textview on my MainActivity, when I do `findViewById(R.id.textView);` on the onReceive method it returns null.

**Here is my onCreate for the MainActivity.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

......

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

IntentFilter broadcastFilter = new IntentFilter(ResponseReceiver.LOCAL_ACTION); 
receiver = new ResponseReceiver();
LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager =   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(receiver, broadcastFilter);

Intent msgIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IntentService.class);
msgIntent.putExtra(StockDataIntentService.PARAM_IN_MSG, getResources().getString(R.string.url));
      startService(msgIntent);

    }

public class ResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 public static final String LOCAL_ACTION =   "com.mypackage.ALL_DONE";
 private Handler handler;

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   String text =intent.getStringExtra(IntentService.PARAM_OUT_MSG);
   TextView txtError = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error);
      }
  }
```

OP for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643385/how-to-update-ui-in-a-broadcastreceiver) was having exact same issue, the accepted answer explains to use a handler etc.. But reading the comments on the answer explain the [BroadastReceiver runs on the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674518/does-broadcastreceiver-onreceive-always-run-in-the-ui-thread) so there is no reason to use a handler. How come I am unable to set the text on the  text view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I do findViewById(R.id.textView); on the onReceive method it
>   returns null.

Because currently not calling `setContentView` method in `onCreate` method of Activity to set layout for current Activity

So, call `setContentView` in onCreate by passing layout it in which `error` TextView available