# Is the Broadcast.onReceive running on the UI thread or not?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, broadcastreceiver

Can someone please help me understand the following from the documentation?

For [onReceive](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent))

> This method is always called within the main thread of its process,
>   unless you explicitly asked for it to be scheduled on a different
>   thread using registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter, String,
>   android.os.Handler). When it runs on the main thread you should never
>   perform long-running operations in it

The following code:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);   
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {    
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {  
        if(Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {  
            Log.d(TAG, "Running in UI thread!");
        }    
    }    
};  
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Always prints that it is running in the UI thread.
Is that not always the case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674518/does-broadcastreceiver-onreceive-always-run-in-the-ui-thread

Comment: Hope this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5676888/1007087 answers your question