# INSTALL_REFERRER intent lifecycle in the context of the app

Tags: android

I know that the INSTALL_REFERRER intent is fired the first time a user opens an app that has been installed from the play store. Here are few things I would like to have clarified: 
Is this intent fired before any activities are launched? 
Is the broadcast receiver responsible for capturing this intent running on the UI thread (i.e. will it block activities from starting)?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timing of the `INSTALL_REFERRER` intent is undocumented - **do not write code that relies on an exact timing of its delivery**. That said, in my experience it is delivered right as an app's process is started for the first time. This will typically occur prior to the launch Activity's `onCreate`, but you absolutely cannot depend on that, as again, it's undocumented and will likely range across devices and potentially versions of Android and Google Play Services.

Though also undocumented, I'll say with very high confidence that your BroadcastReceiver's `onReceive` will be called on the main thread, [as is documented in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674518/does-broadcastreceiver-onreceive-always-run-in-the-ui-thread).